# Best way to send huge data in streaming mode through Python flask application?

Tags: python, pandas, flask, clickhouse, data-stream

I want to create flask application which returns the huge data but the problems is, my api is crashing when it is ask for huge dataset like 6 million records. I want to make my flask application which gives streaming data, where I will just send 100000 records at a time.

What my application looks like:

```
import clickhouse_connect
import orjson
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def send_data():
    client = clickhouse_connect.get_client(host='XXXX', port=XXXX, username='XXXX', password='XXXXX', database = 'XXXXX')
    df = client.query_df("SELECT * FROM Table_Name")
    #table_df.to_dict(orient='records')
    print(type(df.to_dict(orient='dict')))
    return df.to_dict(orient='dict')
```

Suggestions are welcome make my application even faster.

Comment: You might want to look at [streaming patterns](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/streaming/) to avoid aggregating all of the data into a single response. You could paginate through the dataset and provide each page of data as a `yield`ed response